# Excel index() Match() and array issues

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I like working with variables in Excel, it is useful converting everything between commas into a variable, but I got stuck in here, does anyone have an idea how to use array limitations with `INDEX()` function such as seen in the example?

This is an array formula in a table form:

```
{=INDEX([@Column1]=[Column1],MATCH(1,([Column2]="Ready"),0),0)}
```

it returns the right value for the first instance of `[@Column1]=[Column1]` but for the rest, the result is wrong.

A sample can be found in [>>>here<<](https://ln.sync.com/dl/a577bc8b0#2kzya6sn-744ev92d-dqpkz4f7-n48w9isv)<.
I saved this in another language, please let me know if transcription of functions are incorrect when you open. I tested but..you know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not need to be an array, use COUNTIF/S instead:

```
=COUNTIF([Column1],[@Column1])=COUNTIFS([Column1],[@Column1],[Column2],"Ready")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! The data is too large. I thought array would calculate faster in a very complicated environment, isn't it?

Comment: If it worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sure, but this is like a workaround, in a worksheet with around 30.000 lines, countif and derivatives are big trouble, it takes more than a minute for excel respond back to me even if i change only 1 character in a cell each time

Comment: Array formulas will take a lot longer.

Comment: I see thanks, but what is wrong with my array formula then? Not the syntax, i cant find any articles mentioning my case?

Comment: It is the Sytax, 1, The first Criterion of INDEX() is a range not a boolean value. 2. If you are only going to pass one criteria through match use just match normally: `MATCH("Ready",[Column2],0)` and it is no longer an array formula.  3.  For what you want INDEX/MATCH will not work nor is it appropriate as it is designed to return the first match only, it would not get past returning only the first `E1`.  It is this reason you are only getting true on the first group and none others. @hakanSD

Comment: As to the time, you may want to check your other formula for volatile function such as INDIRECT or OFFSET, these calculate every time even if the data to which they refer do not change.  The COUNTIF should not take that lone.  I have tables with thousands of like formulas that take seconds to re calculate.

Comment: I ve been testing. It takes long time, more than a minute to calculate if i use it together with a few 'if' clauses in the same cell, but when separated into 2 columns, countif in one and relative if functions in another coulmn, then it calculates immediately.